# Eye-FI SD Card not working with inbuilt card reader

Tags: linux, debian, drivers, sd-card

I am tring to get my cardreader to work with and eye-fi SD card.

My System is as follow:

```
#uname -a
Linux computer 3.2.0-0.bpo.2-amd64 #1 SMP Thu Mar 15 20:46:44 UTC 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Debian Squeeze

lspci -nn
...
02:00.0 System peripheral [0880]: JMicron Technology Corp. SD/MMC Host Controller [197b:2382] (rev 80)
02:00.2 SD Host controller [0805]: JMicron Technology Corp. Standard SD Host Controller [197b:2381] (rev 80)
02:00.3 System peripheral [0880]: JMicron Technology Corp. MS Host Controller [197b:2383] (rev 80)

### AT BOOT
mmc0: no vmmc regulator found
Registered led device: mmc0::
mmc0: SDHCI controller on PCI [0000:02:00.0] using DMA
### AFTER I INSERT THE CARD
mmc0: error -84 whilst initialising SD card
mmc0: error -84 whilst initialising SD card
mmc0: error -84 whilst initialising SD card
mmc0: error -84 whilst initialising SD card
```

Using the card reader for "normal" SD and SDHC cards seems to work fine. They get registered as devices in /dev/ and can be mounted.

Sadly this is not true for the Eye-Fi Cards (I have tried 2 different models) with the inbuilt card reader. Using the provided USB SD Card Reader and inserting them works and they are mountable etc.

I have tried different methods to get them to run.

1)

```
Creating a file /etc/modprobe.d/sd.conf
options sdhci debug_quirks=0x40
```

2)

```
Creating a file /etc/modprobe.d/sd.conf
options sdhci debug_quirks=1
```

3)
    Removing a firewire driver

```
modprobe -r firewire_ohci
```

So to sum it up. Normal cards work in the reader but the eye-fi cards don't :(

Does anyone have another idea I could checkout?

Comment: I have a laptop (Dell XPS 15) with the same card reader, and need to type `sudo sh -c "echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/rescan"` after I insert a card for the first time, then it works until I reboot. What happens if you do that?

Comment: Can you check your `dmesg | tail` when you're connecting the card?

Answer (score 1):

The Eye-Fi cards seem to require more accurate voltage to power up properly (my own experience with them), I couldn't make it work with my Eye-Fi card reader and it seemed to work with my normal one.

I do have some USB voltage issues on my computer...

I know that practically every camera is able to act as a reader, have you tried to use a camera as a reader?